# How would I go about opening windows on the dash through mouse over?

Tags: gnome-shell, window, ubuntu-dock

Currently to view windows of the same application on the dash you need to click, then out pop the other windows.

[image: Exhibit 1]

How would I go about enabling this on mouse over? I wouldn't call myself a power user but it can be frustrating when I have 3+ windows open of Firefox etc, and I have to click every single time and it feels quite sluggish.

I tried having a little look with the GNOME Tweak Tool but couldn't see anything.

Comment: @pomsky well obviously the ideal would be getting to keep the stock dock. the real answer is that this is a whole project's worth of work but could be very worthwile. a github should be created for this. Dash-to-Panel is truely bugridden.